# Finding zeros with nothing before or after in word document tables

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, find-and-replace, wildcards

I have a word report filled with tables. I need to do a find and replace on all the cells with a single 0 or 0.0 and replace them with something else.

Using wildcards I tried things like:
 [<0>]
[!?,0-9][0][!?,0-9]
[!*][0][!*]
<[!*][0][!*]>

Basically the above with brackets and parentheses in every combination I could think of. I thought the greater and less than would be enough but it's still getting hits on things like 50.0.

Comment: Does it have to be single find and replace?  If not, a staged approach would work.  Find ?0.0 and replace with highlighting (this will highlight 50.0 but not 0 or 0.0).  Then find <0.0> Not Highlighted, and replace with your required text.  Then find <0> Not Highlighted, and again replace with required text.  Then you can remove the highlighting from the 50.0 type entries in one go (if nothing else highlighted, just select all and set No Color for highlight) or else just do a find and replace for ?0.0 With Highlight, and replace with Not Highlight.

Comment: It does not need to be a single approach. I like your idea using the highlights but there are other highlights in the document including numbers I could potentially screw up. I'm still going to give it a try though, thank you. Honestly the 0.0s weren't much of a problem, the single 0s is what was driving me nuts.

Comment: Rather than highlight, you could set the format for the replace to something unique - eg a font colour not used anywhere else.

Comment: True, but would you know why <[0]> or [!?,0-9][0][!?,0-9] isn't working? I swear I wrote something before that worked, I don't know why it's such a problem this time. I want to find a specific character and exclude if there is any character and punctuation before or after it.